# How do I clone/copy an instance of an object in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, clone, instance

Fairly straight forward question but Googling hasn't turned up anything as yet.

How do I copy/clone/duplicate an instance of an object in Coffeescript? I could always just create a `clone()` method which returns a new instance with copied values, but that seems like an error-prone way to go about it.

Does CoffeeScript offer a simpler solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might work.

```
clone = (obj) ->
  return obj  if obj is null or typeof (obj) isnt "object"
  temp = new obj.constructor()
  for key of obj
    temp[key] = clone(obj[key])
  temp
```

Adopted from : [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: It should be `new obj.constructor()`. Otherwise you'll get a "Cannot convert 'temp' to object."

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to Larry Battle for the hint:

John Resig's solution of using jQuery.extend works brilliantly!

```
// Shallow copy
newObject = $.extend({}, oldObject);

// Deep copy
newObject = $.extend(true, {}, oldObject);
```

More information can be found in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).

Comment: When I do this, changing a property in the new object ends up changing in the old one, so how is this a "copy" ?

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't sound right :) Are you editing primitive properties or complex properties? You may need to use the deep copy if you're editing nested properties. Here's John Resig's original answer for JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/a/122704/746890 (John was the creator of jQuery).

Comment: I think I sorted it.  I think it was KnockoutJS wrapping my JS object as a KO VM.

Answer (score 2):

From The CoffeeScript Cookbook:

http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/classes_and_objects/cloning

Underscore.js also has a shallow clone function:

http://underscorejs.org/#clone